# What are some elementary bounds for Mertens' Third Theorem?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

In particular, I am looking for $A$ and $B$ such that, for all $x>s$,
$$\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log x} B< \prod_{  p \leq x} \frac{p-1}{p}<\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log x}A.$$
Rosser provides both lower and upper bounds, where the former holds for $x>285$ and the latter for $x>1$. I have done research and can not find a lower bound that holds for small $s$, such as $s=1$. Are there any such lower bounds that hold for smaller $s$?

Comment: The PNT gives the rate of convergence of $\log x \prod_{p\le x} (1-1/p)$ to $e^{-\gamma}$ from which you can find the optimal $A,B$ for a given $s$.

Comment: @reuns How do you get *optimal* bounds for small $s$ from an *asymptotic* like PNT, especially since the error terms of PNT (even if you assume RH) aren't all that optimistic?

Comment: @user436658 A>1,B<1 thus the optimal $A,B$ can be found numerically. In practice $B$ is found from the first few $x$ and we'll need a pretty big $x$ such that $e^\gamma \log x\prod_{  p \leq x} \frac{p-1}{p}>1$

Comment: @reuns Erm... sorry... how could a product of factors $<1$ like $\prod_{  p \leq x} \frac{p-1}{p}$ *ever* be $>1$? Moreover, there's still a factor of $\displaystyle\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log x}$ in the original question. So you'd need a combination of rather sharp error terms *plus* numerical evidence for (not so) small $x$, right?

Comment: @user436658 No, $\lim_{x\to \infty} e^\gamma \log x\prod_{  p \leq x} \frac{p-1}{p}=1$, the PNT gives a constant such that $f(x)=e^\gamma \log x\prod_{  p \leq x} \frac{p-1}{p}-1\in (-C/\log x,C/\log x)$, find some $u,v\ge s$ such that $f(u)<1,f(v)>1$ then check up to $x=\exp(C \max(|f(u)|, |f(v)|))$